# File Upload - Handle on IE8/IE9

Tags: jquery, html, forms, file, internet-explorer-8

I am using the JQuery validation plugin.  As I have found out, I can't use FileData on IE8/IE9.  The problem is, due to some reasons beyond my control, I also can't use something like IFrame of Flash to handle my files.

At the moment, my submitHandler is like the following

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    if( window.FormData === undefined ) {
        alert("UNDEFINED");
    } else {
        formData   = new FormData(),
            params     = $(form).serializeArray(),
            fileOne    = $(form).find('[name="fileOne"]')[0].files,
            fileTwo    = $(form).find('[name="fileTwo"]')[0].files;

        if(fileOne.length != 0) {
            $.each(fileOne, function(i, file) {
                formData.append('fileOne-' + i, file);
            });
        }

        if(fileTwo.length != 0) {
            $.each(fileTwo, function(i, file) {
                formData.append('fileTwo-' + i, file);
            });
        }

        $.each(params, function(i, val) {
            formData.append(val.name, val.value);
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/process.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: formData,
            mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        }).done(function (response) {

            });
        return false;
    }
},
```

So, it works as normal, but if it does not support FormData, at the moment I have it alerting Undefined.  What I need it to do however is keep the validation on the other form fields because this seems to work on IE8, but to ignore anything to do with the uploaded files.  So how would I get it calling my php script for IE8/IE9?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Exclude file validation if FormData object doesn't exist

```
if (typeof formData == "undefined") {
   //don't do file validation
}
```

Comment: Then do I just trigger the submit?  Also, is it possible to do normal validation in this and still get the file in PHP?  When I try, the normal validation works, but the File is not passed to PHP.

Comment: you are better just going with a simple post/refresh page on < ie10 than ajaxing without a file

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: you just post the data ,no ajax